# Light Weight Render Pipeline is not supported in Oculus Go? Because the app crashes when opening

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusgo

Is LWRP supported on Oculus Go or not? I am using Unity 2019.1.0f2 version and I have changed every setting in Unity, but somehow the application always crashes before the scene even loads.
Will this also occur in Oculus Quest? Is there any work around?

Comment: It should work, at least it does with the Rift as I'm currently making a project using LWRP with the rift

Comment: It works with the rift, Go is causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dealing with a similar issue on Quest + Unity 2019 and what solved it for me was removing Vulkan Graphics API Options in Player Settings. If it's on "Auto", just uncheck it and remove Vulkan. After that LWRP worked for Oculus Quest.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it on Go. Problem was that the project had too many models and too many polygons in it due to which the processor on Go was lagging and that is the reason for it to crash